# why MediaRecorder cannot support UHD 4K in Samsung note8 by android camera2 api?

Tags: android, mediarecorder

In Samsung note 8, 
`StreamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class)`
 return supported video resolutions which does not contains 3840 X 2160, so MediaRecorder  does not support to  record UHD 4k resolution video .
   But I found the note8 system camera app could support 3840x2160, and the 3rd party app Filmic supports 3840x2160, 
    My question is, how can we support UHD as Filmic does?